# K-means clustering with Pearson_Correlation

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means, pearson-correlation

I'm trying to replicate a feature in Systat, which is k-means clustering with Pearson correlation. I saw that a package called ClusterR allows you to do this by specifying a bunch of parameters. I have a file with two columns, one from Panelist, the other of regression coefficients. My aim is to create 2 clusters and have one of them assigned to each Panelist. The code I wrote is below. The result I get is an empty table. Thank you in advance for any help or guidance your povide.

> library(utils)
> library(cluster)
> library("ClusterR")
> library(dplyr)

## Data

> data <- read.csv("/Users/sr/Documents/src/Learning/R-BimiProject/DoctorPanelistCoefficients.csv")
> data <- as.data.frame(data)
> data <- group_by(data, Panelist)
>
> ## Define 'entire_sample'
>
> entire_sample <- nrow(data)

> ## Invoke ClusterR
>
> clusters <- Clara_Medoids(

- ```
  data=data,
  ```
- ```
  clusters=2,
  ```
- ```
  samples=entire_sample,
  ```
- ```
  sample_size=1,
  ```
- ```
  distance_metric="pearson_correlation",
  ```
- ```
  minkowski_p=1,
  ```
- ```
  threads=1,
  ```
- ```
  swap_phase=TRUE,
  ```
- ```
  fuzzy=FALSE,
  ```
- ```
  verbose=FALSE,
  ```
- ```
  seed=1
  ```
- )

> ## Create an Excel file with the results
>
> write.xlsx(clusters$clusterID, file = "ClusterID.xlsx")

## What I Tried and Expected Section

What I tried: code above
What I expected: a table with cluster assignments (1 or 2) to each panelist.

Comment: Your example is not reproducible. You have to add sample data. By including the parameter setting only you might not receive an answer to your issue.